# Discrete value supplied to continuous scale for xy scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, continuous

Apologies for another question on this subject, but I have read the others and it hasn't helped me in any way.

I am trying to create a generic xy scatterplot of geochemistry which, once the code is working, will have several layers of points added based on the sample. The code I am using I have adapted from some I was originally using with a discrete x axis but I have changed this variable to continuous and it still isn't working. I do not want to remove the continuous scale commands so it is set automatically, because I want to compare the data between similar graphs with similar scales.

Here is a subset of my data:

```
Si <- structure(list(Zr_TiO2 = c(83.19, 115.64, 90.63, 179.36, 526.05, 104.61, 51.61, 72.66, 255.9, 109.9, 96.11, 246.82, 83.33, 99.33, 86.62), SiO2 = c(54.1, 43.8, 48.92, 39.81, 54.99, 49.28, 49.28, 46.4, 53.9, 49.25, 48.06, 55.31, 48.13, 51.18, 51.09), Sample = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("Zr_TiO2", "SiO2", "Sample"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here is the code I am using:

```
a <- Si$Zr_TiO2[Si$Sample == '1']
Si$Zr_TiO2 <- factor(Si$Zr_TiO2,levels = a)
ggplot(data=Si[Si$Sample == '1',]) +
geom_point(aes(y=SiO2, x=Zr_TiO2,group = a), pch=0, colour="black", size=0.8) +
scale_y_continuous("SiO2 (ppm))", limits = c(0,90), breaks=c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90)) +
scale_x_continuous("Zr / TiO2", limits = c(0,500), breaks=c(0,100,200,300,400,500))
```

Comment: Your variable `Zr_TiO2` is factor so you get the error about scales. With line `Si$Zr_TiO2 <- factor(Si$Zr_TiO2,levels = a)` you convert numeric values to factor.

Comment: Thanks for looking Didzis. I have tried removing the factor command and the entire line of code but the error is still occurring.

Comment: Works for me wihtout problems. Also I think you don't need this `group=a` statment in your code

Comment: Just restarted the software and it worked - thank you very much for your help!